# What do the operators |= and <<= do?

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, rfid, valarray

I have an Arduino sketch, which is basically c++, that has these lines of code in it:

```
uint32_t cardid = uid[0];
cardid <<= 8;
cardid |= uid[1];
```

The Arduino is connected to a pn532 RFID reader so basically it scans the card that comes in range and prints the UID on it. 
But I cannot understand what the operators |= and <<= do.
I found online that they have something to do with valarrays but I have never used such things.

Comment: _"they have something to do with valarrays"_ No. These are the bitwise OR and left shift operators.

Comment: Downvoted for lack of research effort. This is not hard to google.

Answer (score 3):

In general these operators are shortcuts:

```
a <<= b   -->   a = a << b
a |= b    -->   a = a | b
```

In the given example, this code generates a 16 bit value from two 8 bit values. Given

```
uid[0] = 0x12
uid[1] = 0x34
```

then

```
uint32_t cardid = uid[0];  // cardid is now 0x12
cardid <<= 8;              // shifts the value 8 bits to the left -> 0x1200
cardid |= uid[1];          // applies the OR operator -> 0x1200 | 0x34 = 0x1234
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ allows `+= *= |= &= ...` so in your case the first one `<<=` is called `right shift assignment` operator which is a shortcut of Shifting the bits of the same lValue then assigning the result to it itself:

```
int a = 7;
a <<= 2;
a = a << 2; // This line is identical to the one above.
```

The second `|=` is called `Bitwise Or Assignment` operator which is a shortcut of bitwise Or-ing the bits of the same lValue and then assign the result to it itself:

```
int a = 7;
a |= 2;
a = a | 2; // This line is identical to the one above.
```

- Both of the operators works on bits.

Answer (score 0):

These are bitwise operators (written as shortcuts).

**cardid <<= 8;** is same as **cardid = (cardid << 8);**
This does an arithmetic left shift, that is essentially multiplying by 2^8 in this case.

**cardid |= uid[1];** is same as **cardid = (cardid | uid[1]);**
This performs bitwise OR, that is, it sets in bits in cardid which are also set in uid.